# Fedora booting failure under VirtualBox

Tags: fedora, spinlock

A student of mine stuck with a Fedora virtual machine under VirtualBox:

[image]

I do not even recognize what is going on here.

Do you have a clue what is going on? (on the left you see another VM that is broadcasted from me, a working instance of this VM)

Does this have anything to do with

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/658783 ?

Comment: The kernel is crashing. Can't tell more than that. Does the same problem happen with 1) a current Fedora release like Fedora 33 and 2) the newest VirtualBox, if this isn't already that?

Comment: This is the latest VirtualBox and for all the group but this student it works. Could this be a missing VT-x option in the BIOS?

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1652845 search for "enable nesting". They consider this WONTFIX. I gave a Fedora 33 image to my student, I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1652845

describes the problem, search for "enable nesting". They say that Red Hat won't fix this problem with Fedora 28.

mattdm's suggestion of creating a fresh Fedora VM, Fedora 33 worked.

Comment: Is your student running on a Power system? It looks to be i686 in the screenshots. I'm not sure that's the same bug at all. In any case, I'm glad F33 worked.

Comment: What do you mean by Power system?

Comment: IBM Power CPU architecture. Note "ppc64le" in the bug descroption. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_POWER_microprocessors. Not compatible with Intel/AMD systems and a different set of virtualization technologies.

Comment: I see. She uses Intel/AMD.

Comment: Yeah, so I think that's a different bug which happens to produce something that looks like similar symptoms.